# ctest custom warning exception

Tags: cmake, ctest

Can anyone explain me how to filter out the below warning from dashboard?

warning: #warning "deprecated"
...../vcl_deprecated_header.h:10:3: warning: #warning "deprecated" [-Wcpp]
 # warning "deprecated"

So far I tried having below in CTestCustom.cmake

set(CTEST_CUSTOM_WARNING_EXCEPTION
  ${CTEST_CUSTOM_WARNING_EXCEPTION}
  ".*vcl_deprecated_header.*warning.*"
  "vcl_deprecated_header"
...
)

I have ctest_read_custom_files after ctest_confgiure

see build notes - http://dash.orfeo-toolbox.org/viewNotes.php?buildid=160097

Answer (score -1):

Try to Compile with `-Wno-cpp` to suppress the warning?

Comment: I want to supress the warnings on dashboard. -Wno-cpp will work but thats not what I want here

Comment: I think this should go in the comment section of the question instead of being an answer.